# Problem with updating/reinstalling kite for atom

Tags: atom-editor, kite

today I got a notification in atom that kite needed to be updated so I tried updating it but got an error. I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it but also got the same error.

This is the error:

```
Installing “kite@0.180.0” failed.Hide output…

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '.../MEed5GFSR/Ibhv+hzsFe'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bechara/.atom/.apm/_logs/2020-04-16T14_42_47_449Z-debug.log
```

And this is the content of the file /Users/bechara/.atom/.apm/_logs/2020-04-16T14_42_47_449Z-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '--globalconfig',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/bechara/.atom/.apm/.apmrc',
1 verbose cli   '--userconfig',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/bechara/.atom/.apmrc',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'https://www.atom.io/api/packages/kite/versions/0.180.0/tarball',
1 verbose cli   '--target=4.2.7',
1 verbose cli   '--disturl=https://atom.io/download/electron',
1 verbose cli   '--arch=x64',
1 verbose cli   '--global-style' ]
2 info using npm@6.2.0
3 info using node@v10.2.1
4 verbose npm-session 5d45507431a719ec
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://www.atom.io/api/packages/kite/versions/0.180.0/tarball 2220ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote remote manifest for undefined@https://www.atom.io/api/packages/kite/versions/0.180.0/tarball fetched in 2246ms
9 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 2439ms
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
12 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
13 silly install loadShrinkwrap
14 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 1ms
15 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
16 silly resolveWithNewModule kite@0.180.0 checking installable status
17 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/element-resize-detector 532ms (from cache)
18 silly pacote range manifest for element-resize-detector@^1.1.11 fetched in 534ms
19 silly resolveWithNewModule element-resize-detector@1.2.1 checking installable status
20 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tiny-relative-date 150ms (from cache)
21 silly pacote range manifest for tiny-relative-date@^1.3.0 fetched in 151ms
22 silly resolveWithNewModule tiny-relative-date@1.3.0 checking installable status
23 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore-plus 5ms (from cache)
24 silly pacote range manifest for underscore-plus@^1 fetched in 7ms
25 silly resolveWithNewModule underscore-plus@1.7.0 checking installable status
26 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/getmac 2363ms (from cache)
27 silly pacote version manifest for getmac@1.2.1 fetched in 2366ms
28 silly resolveWithNewModule getmac@1.2.1 checking installable status
29 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/md5 2615ms (from cache)
30 silly pacote range manifest for md5@^2.2.0 fetched in 2615ms
31 silly resolveWithNewModule md5@2.2.1 checking installable status
32 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/analytics-node 2654ms (from cache)
33 silly pacote range manifest for analytics-node@^3.1.1 fetched in 2657ms
34 silly resolveWithNewModule analytics-node@3.3.0 checking installable status
35 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rollbar 2655ms (from cache)
36 silly pacote range manifest for rollbar@^2.3.8 fetched in 2659ms
37 silly resolveWithNewModule rollbar@2.15.1 checking installable status
38 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kite-installer 2866ms (from cache)
39 silly pacote version manifest for kite-installer@=3.16.0 fetched in 2869ms
40 silly resolveWithNewModule kite-installer@3.16.0 checking installable status
41 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kite-connector 2889ms (from cache)
42 silly pacote version manifest for kite-connector@=3.12.0 fetched in 2891ms
43 silly resolveWithNewModule kite-connector@3.12.0 checking installable status
44 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kite-api 2913ms (from cache)
45 silly pacote version manifest for kite-api@=3.12.0 fetched in 2915ms
46 silly resolveWithNewModule kite-api@3.12.0 checking installable status
47 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fuzzaldrin-plus 2938ms (from cache)
48 silly pacote range manifest for fuzzaldrin-plus@^0.4.1 fetched in 2939ms
49 silly resolveWithNewModule fuzzaldrin-plus@0.4.1 checking installable status
50 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash 3034ms (from cache)
51 silly pacote range manifest for lodash@^4.17.11 fetched in 3035ms
52 silly resolveWithNewModule lodash@4.17.15 checking installable status
53 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/remove-trailing-slash 24ms (from cache)
54 silly pacote range manifest for remove-trailing-slash@^0.1.0 fetched in 25ms
55 silly resolveWithNewModule remove-trailing-slash@0.1.0 checking installable status
56 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isstring 150ms (from cache)
57 silly pacote range manifest for lodash.isstring@^4.0.1 fetched in 151ms
58 silly resolveWithNewModule lodash.isstring@4.0.1 checking installable status
59 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@segment%2floosely-validate-event 173ms (from cache)
60 silly pacote range manifest for @segment/loosely-validate-event@^2.0.0 fetched in 174ms
61 silly resolveWithNewModule @segment/loosely-validate-event@2.0.0 checking installable status
62 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/axios 175ms (from cache)
63 silly pacote range manifest for axios@^0.17.1 fetched in 178ms
64 silly resolveWithNewModule axios@0.17.1 checking installable status
65 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/axios-retry 185ms (from cache)
66 silly pacote range manifest for axios-retry@^3.0.2 fetched in 186ms
67 silly resolveWithNewModule axios-retry@3.1.2 checking installable status
68 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid 200ms (from cache)
69 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander 203ms (from cache)
70 silly pacote range manifest for uuid@^3.2.1 fetched in 203ms
71 silly resolveWithNewModule uuid@3.4.0 checking installable status
72 silly pacote range manifest for commander@^2.9.0 fetched in 206ms
73 silly resolveWithNewModule commander@2.20.3 checking installable status
74 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms 206ms (from cache)
75 silly pacote range manifest for ms@^2.0.0 fetched in 207ms
76 silly resolveWithNewModule ms@2.1.2 checking installable status
77 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/component-type 174ms (from cache)
78 silly pacote range manifest for component-type@^1.2.1 fetched in 176ms
79 silly resolveWithNewModule component-type@1.2.1 checking installable status
80 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/join-component 193ms (from cache)
81 silly pacote range manifest for join-component@^1.1.0 fetched in 196ms
82 silly resolveWithNewModule join-component@1.1.0 checking installable status
83 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/follow-redirects 186ms (from cache)
84 silly pacote range manifest for follow-redirects@^1.2.5 fetched in 188ms
85 silly resolveWithNewModule follow-redirects@1.11.0 checking installable status
86 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-buffer 240ms (from cache)
87 silly pacote range manifest for is-buffer@^1.1.5 fetched in 241ms
88 silly resolveWithNewModule is-buffer@1.1.6 checking installable status
89 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug 202ms (from cache)
90 silly pacote range manifest for debug@^3.0.0 fetched in 204ms
91 silly resolveWithNewModule debug@3.2.6 checking installable status
92 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-retry-allowed 195ms (from cache)
93 silly pacote range manifest for is-retry-allowed@^1.1.0 fetched in 196ms
94 silly resolveWithNewModule is-retry-allowed@1.2.0 checking installable status
95 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/charenc 155ms (from cache)
96 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/crypt 155ms (from cache)
97 silly pacote range manifest for charenc@~0.0.1 fetched in 156ms
98 silly resolveWithNewModule charenc@0.0.2 checking installable status
99 silly pacote range manifest for crypt@~0.0.1 fetched in 157ms
100 silly resolveWithNewModule crypt@0.0.2 checking installable status
101 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/batch-processor 134ms (from cache)
102 silly pacote version manifest for batch-processor@1.0.0 fetched in 135ms
103 silly resolveWithNewModule batch-processor@1.0.0 checking installable status
104 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/extract-opts 191ms (from cache)
105 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for extract-opts@^3.2.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '.../MEed5GFSR/Ibhv+hzsFe'
106 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
107 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 7044ms
108 silly saveTree apm-install-dir-120316-10919-1hco8zm.sruq
108 silly saveTree `-- kite@0.180.0
108 silly saveTree   +-- analytics-node@3.3.0
108 silly saveTree   | +-- @segment/loosely-validate-event@2.0.0
108 silly saveTree   | | +-- component-type@1.2.1
108 silly saveTree   | | `-- join-component@1.1.0
108 silly saveTree   | +-- axios-retry@3.1.2
108 silly saveTree   | | `-- is-retry-allowed@1.2.0
108 silly saveTree   | +-- axios@0.17.1
108 silly saveTree   | | +-- follow-redirects@1.11.0
108 silly saveTree   | | | `-- debug@3.2.6
108 silly saveTree   | | |   `-- ms@2.1.2
108 silly saveTree   | | `-- is-buffer@1.1.6
108 silly saveTree   | +-- commander@2.20.3
108 silly saveTree   | +-- lodash.isstring@4.0.1
108 silly saveTree   | +-- md5@2.2.1
108 silly saveTree   | | +-- charenc@0.0.2
108 silly saveTree   | | `-- crypt@0.0.2
108 silly saveTree   | +-- ms@2.1.2
108 silly saveTree   | +-- remove-trailing-slash@0.1.0
108 silly saveTree   | `-- uuid@3.4.0
108 silly saveTree   +-- element-resize-detector@1.2.1
108 silly saveTree   | `-- batch-processor@1.0.0
108 silly saveTree   +-- fuzzaldrin-plus@0.4.1
108 silly saveTree   +-- getmac@1.2.1
108 silly saveTree   +-- kite-api@3.12.0
108 silly saveTree   +-- kite-connector@3.12.0
108 silly saveTree   +-- kite-installer@3.16.0
108 silly saveTree   | `-- rollbar@2.15.1
108 silly saveTree   +-- lodash@4.17.15
108 silly saveTree   +-- md5@2.2.1
108 silly saveTree   +-- rollbar@2.15.1
108 silly saveTree   +-- tiny-relative-date@1.3.0
108 silly saveTree   `-- underscore-plus@1.7.0
109 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '.../MEed5GFSR/Ibhv+hzsFe'
109 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
109 verbose stack     at parseJson (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
109 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50)
109 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
110 verbose cwd /private/var/folders/lq/53bnqw5x67z4jw1kzm3b2vk00000gn/T/apm-install-dir-120316-10919-1hco8zm.sruq
111 verbose Darwin 19.4.0
112 verbose argv "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/Users/bechara/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/Users/bechara/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "https://www.atom.io/api/packages/kite/versions/0.180.0/tarball" "--target=4.2.7" "--disturl=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--arch=x64" "--global-style"
113 verbose node v10.2.1
114 verbose npm  v6.2.0
115 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '.../MEed5GFSR/Ibhv+hzsFe'
116 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I also tried installing it from the Kite Copilot and got this error:

```
/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/bin/apm "install kite": exit status 1
```

How can I fix it and reinstall it?

Thank you.

Comment: I will try to contact the Kite support team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue when installing by deleting the file ~/.atom/.apm